# How can i import a single type, class, const or enum from a sub namespace inside from a Typescript module?

Tags: typescript

I am working with Google Cloud Platform and Typescript.

I've working with some code and varialbes that should implement specific GPC types. like:

```
import { protos } from "@google-cloud/aiplatform";

class myClass {
  public async getModelById(id: string): Promise<protos.google.cloud.aiplatform.v1beta1.IModel>
  { /* ... */ }

  public async getTrainingPipelineById(id: string): Promise<protos.google.cloud.aiplatform.v1beta1.ITrainingPipeline>
  { /* ... */ }
}
```

I would like to import only **types**, **classes** and **enums** I would like to use, for instance

```
import { IModel, ITrainingPipeline } from "@google-cloud/aiplatform".protos.google.cloud.aiplatform.v1beta1 ;
// I know that the code above does not works, but you got the idea


class myClass {
  public async getModelById(id: string): Promise<IModel>
  { /* ... */ }

  public async getTrainingPipelineById(id: string): Promise<ITrainingPipeline>
  { /* ... */ }
}
```

How can i import a single type, class or enum from a sub namespace inside from a module?

Comment: You can use the `import` alias syntax: `import IModel = protos.google.cloud.aiplatform.v1beta1.IModel;`

Answer (score 2):

In short, [you can't do that](https://github.com/babel/babel/issues/4996).

Summarizing from the link: even though the syntax *looks* similar, importing named imports is not the same thing as destructuring an object so you can't nest it like you can with destructuring. You will have to use two statements:

```
import { protos } from "@google-cloud/aiplatform";
let {google: {cloud: {aiplatform: {v1beta1: {IModel, ITrainingPipeline}}}}} = protos;

// or, perhaps more readably
let {IModel, ITrainingPipeline} = protos.google.cloud.aiplatform.v1beta1;
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=1&ssl=3&ssc=1&pln=1&pc=1#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAbzmKEYQM5wL5wGaohwBEAAgOYQTkA2ApgLQDGNEArgCYD0AhsGDR4w80EMQDcAWABQTCADsM8BJWr0AXIhbsOmhHwFCRUEHoBuARgBGdGDwt6AkgFkIHOjWxevcALzJUdAwpaSA)

Comment: This notation above works for objects and properties, In the case of Type Definition it seems to does not works

> Property 'ITrainingPipeline' does not exist on type 'typeof v1beta1'.ts(2339)

OBS the type DOES exists

Comment: @DanielSantos: Did you ever figure this out? I see the same problem with trying to alias the interfaces.

Not sure if this is too hacky, but this seems to work: `
interface IJob extends protos.google.cloud.video.transcoder.v1.IJob {};
`